# Apache in Linux cannot load my data from mysql, but in windows working normally

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, ubuntu

Please help me, I migrated my web file from Windows Apache to Linux Apache server. When I try to access the web, the web runs normally, but, in one of my web pages, I must display large quantity of data which I get from MySQL database (join table)... In windows, that data is displaying sequentially until it finishes loading the data (no matter how many rows the data is). But, in Linux, the data is buffering then it will be displayed in my web page. The problem is, when the data is too large to display, like 2000 rows, the Apache in Linux cannot load normally like in windows. It cannot display the data that I want it to display. Please help me, I'm confused. I have tried to browse but i have no clue about it. (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Try adding `set_time_limit(0);` to your config file...

Comment: i try that... hope this works...

Comment: i get the solution by myself...
i disable deflate module on apache2 in Linux...
and the web works normally! ^^ thx